# How to select grouped column in one table and other column in different table with third table with foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, select

I am using my PostgreSQL and here is explanation what is wrong:

1. I have first table `river_changes` and it has structure:

| id_hydro | size | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2002 |
| 1 | 55 | 1992 |
| 2 | 5 | 2005 |
| 2 | 20 | 2022 |
| 2 | 10 | 2016 |
| 3 | 80 | 2018 |
| 3 | 40 | 1999 |
| 3 | 60 | 1987 |

2. I have second table `hydro_river`:

| id_hydro | id_river |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 240 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 34 |
| 5 | 96 |
| 6 | 43 |
| 7 | 78 |
| 8 | 85 |

3. And the last one `river`:

| name | id_river |
| --- | --- |
| one | 240 |
| two | 12 |
| three | 7 |
| four | 34 |
| five | 96 |
| fgh | 43 |
| jgh | 78 |
| pop | 85 |

So, i have my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT river.name, AVG(river_changes.size)
FROM river, hydro, river_changes
WHERE river_changes.id_hydro = hydro.id_hydro
     AND hydro.id_river = river.id_river;
```

What is my problem? I do not know where i have to place "GROUP BY"

I have to find avarage river_changes.size and find name for that river.
I need it to show river's name and size through years in average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group by goes after the where clause. I believe you're looking for something like this.

```
SELECT river.name, AVG(river_changes.size) AS AverageSize
FROM river
    INNER JOIN hydro_river ON hydro_river.id_river = river.id_river
    INNER JOIN river_changes ON river_changes.id_hydro = hydro_river.id_hydro
GROUP BY river.name;
```

This is the output.

| name | AverageSize |
| --- | --- |
| one | 278 |
| three | 60 |
| two | 11 |

You can find the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3f404da703cc676c6743b7a691001096).

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your'e looking for then? Happy to offer alternative solutions. Maybe put your data in a Fiddle so we can see a demo.

Comment: Your solution correct, but my code is not, because this language has problems with exporting few tables with FROM statmen. I had to use INNER JOIN statements.

Comment: Ok, wasn’t aware that was the part you were having trouble with. I’ve updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has some problems with exporting more then 1 table with FROM statemen. Code worked with INNER JOIN.